# if sentence contains string

Tags: javascript, jquery

If a sentence contains "Hello World" (no quotes) then I need to return true and do something. Possible sentences could be like this:

```
var sentence = "This is my Hello World and I like widgets."
var sentence = "Hello World - the beginning of all"
var sentence = "Welcome to Hello World"

if ( sentence.contains('Hello World') ){
alert('Yes');
} else {
alert('No');
}
```

I know the .contains does not work, so I'm looking for something does work. Regex is the enemy here.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The method you're looking for is `indexOf` ([Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexOf.asp)).  Try the following

```
if (sentence.indexOf('Hello World') >= 0) { 
  alert('Yes');
} else { 
  alert('No');
}
```

Comment: Don't just try it.  Do it.  ;)

Comment: @Stephen, is there an extra semantic that `!== false` adds here or is it just for readability?

Comment: Eh, sorry.  I just deleted that part of the comment, Jared.  In fact, if the string doesn't exist, `indexOf` returns `-1` not `false`.

Comment: @Stephen, ok that was my understanding and I was wondering how `!== false` would work in that situation (still fairly new to javascript).

Comment: Sorry!  I didn't mean to confuse!

Comment: @Stephen, no worries. It actually prompted me to do further reading on strict vs. non-strict equality in javascript and I learned quite a bit.  So overall a win :)

Answer (score 8):

Try this instead:

```
if (sentence.indexOf("Hello World") != -1)
{
    alert("Yes");
}
else
{
    alert("No");
}
```